# Unable to install ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I am new to Ubuntu,i managed to install it on my PC (with windows 10).
At the end of installation it asked me to restart but after that my computer directly booted in windows, even i am not able to see the DRIVE where ubuntu is installed in windows

Comment: my pc is older one and when i type Confirm-SecureBootUEFI it shows Cmdlet not supported on this platform

Comment: i have earlier installed backbox (Linux distribution based on Ubuntu) which was working fine

Answer (score 2):

First you have to boot into Windows and **disable hibernation** and **Fast Boot** from within there.

To disable hibernation open **command prompt as administrator** and execute this command:

```
powercfg /h off
```

To disable Fast Boot open **Control Panel** go to **Energy Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and uncheck Fast Boot. After these steps **shutdown** the machine (do **NOT reboot**) completely.

Then try to change the boot order in **BIOS (UEFI)** settings.
Select Ubuntu to be the default operating system to boot.

In case your computer has a **legacy BIOS** instead of an UEFI based,
(Fast Boot might not be an option)
reinstall the GRUB boot loader.

Boot from ubuntu install media, open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt  
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sd*
```

Note : `sd*` = disk | `sd**` = system partition

If you do not know the partition numbers you can easily identify them with **GParted**.
This (Graphic User Interface) tool is already included in the Ubuntu installation media.

Comment: how can i know which is my system partition and which is disk. name for my whole harddisk is sda2 and parition where ubuntu is installed is sda11

Comment: @ShubhamGupta : the whole disk is sda - system partition is sda11 - if you are not sure please make a screenshot from gparted output, load it up somewhere and provide me with the link. :)

Comment: here it is http://s9.postimg.org/u7lgqd2kf/Screenshot_from_2015_10_06_10_40_58.png

Comment: @ShubhamGupta : It looks like you installed ubuntu twice. I suggest : delete partition 11 (except if you placed something else in there) then execute the commands from ubuntu install media using sda ( * ) and sda9 ( ** ) - post back results ... Good luck ! :)